Why can’t we say Halleluyah?
We are allowed to say names like Yirmiyah and Azariah which have Hashem’s name, why is it considered saying Hashem’s name in vain to say Halleluyah? (obviously not when it’s part of davening).

Who said it's a problem?

https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/866998 - this should answer it, he ends up saying that there is room to be lenient but one should try to be machmir

I’m not saying whether it’s ok or not, but whereas when saying a name you are not intending to say G-D’S name, when saying hallelujah one is actually intending to say his name i.e. praise his name.
